# calling somepage.php from wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have an issue with my custom wordpress template.
This is what I have done. I have created a custom template in wordpress. I have added a set_include_path to where my custom php page is. Then I open the page with require 'testpher.php'. This is working as intended, but the thing is. At the end of the customtemplate file, the wordpress function get_footer() should be called. In my current situation this doesn't happen. After my testpher.php has been executed, the page is done.
Here is the code of the template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Test Pascal
*/

/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */
include '../../testpher.php';

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            set_include_path('/var/www/wordpress/wp-content');
            require 'testpher.php';

            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How do I get wordpress to run the get_footer() function, after my custom page has been loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the require_once function instead?

Comment: ... and what's in your `testpher.php`

Comment: Enable PHP errors. There could be a error in your `testpher.php` that prevents the rest of the pages PHP from being processed.

Comment: WizardCoder's answer got my on the right track again. As it turned out, it was not my code that was at fault, but the funtion that was called after my code ran generated an error.